# Can't fetch data from the analysis tab on Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape some tabular content from a website. The data loading process on this [website](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL) has changed dramatically. Previously, the necessary data could be found within some script tags in the page source. I looked into the endpoint through dev tools but could not find any data there. I'm not sure if I missed anything in there, though. I'm interested in the table located under `Revenue Estimate`. This is something how I could fetch the content.

```
import re
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    data = re.findall(r'root.App.main[^{]+([\s\S].*);',res.text)[0]
    jsoncontent = json.loads(data)

    # pprint(jsoncontent)

    try:
        container = jsoncontent['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']['earningsTrend']
    except TypeError: container = ""

    pprint(container)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pandas DataFrame to get the  `Revenue Estimate` table data as follows:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers= {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}

res = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis?p=AAPL&guccounter=1", headers=headers).text
#print(res)
df= pd.read_html(res)[1]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      Revenue Estimate Current Qtr. (Mar 2023) Next Qtr. (Jun 2023) Current Year (2023) Next Year (2024)
0          No. of Analysts                      24                   23                  39               36
1            Avg. Estimate                  93.19B               85.59B             392.39B          417.75B
2             Low Estimate                  91.81B               81.32B             378.62B          398.67B
3            High Estimate                  98.84B               90.12B             414.04B          438.76B
4           Year Ago Sales                  97.28B               82.96B             394.33B          392.39B
5  Sales Growth (year/est)                  -4.20%                3.20%              -0.50%            6.50%
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'finance.yahoo.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,de-CH;q=0.4,es;q=0.3',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'dnt': '1',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.78',
}

params = {
    'p': 'AAPL',
}

response = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/analysis', params=params, headers=headers)
```

and efter that parse the desired values from `response.content`.